# Is it possible to expire sessions based on their value?

Tags: php, session

I'm guessing the answer is no, but I'm trying to solve this potential security scenario:

*User A* is logged in via Session 1

*User B* get's *User A*'s password and logs into Session 2

*User A* realizes their account is compromised somehow and changes their password.

At the time of password change, I'd like it to also log User B out.  So in other words I want to logout all users with `$_SESSION['userid'] == 123`.

I don't think there is a way to do this in PHP however without clearing all SESSIONS for all users, but I wanted to double check.

Comment: `I don't think there is a way to do this in PHP`: There are many ways of doing this but whether they are efficient or not is another question. One way would be to store the hashed password (the one they entered on login) in session and compare it with the one stored in the database on every page load. This way once the password is changed then all subsequent page loads will result in invalid login for user B. Since the question was hypothetical, the answer as well is :)

Comment: You could log them out but User B would not be logged out until s/he tried to refresh the page or travel to another page. Killing the actual session would be the largest problem.

Comment: Do you need to know if a user is logged in more than one session?

Comment: Hanky: This is thinking out of the box, but seems like a decent amount of overhead to add for an edge case...

Comment: Maxi: Not necessarily, just need to kill all users where SESSION['userid'] set to X

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly possible. Using the standard file-based session storage, all you have to do is find the directory in which the sessions are stored, iterate each file, inspect it and purge it if it's a session of that user. The best method would probably be to use `session_id()` with the file name of the session file, then `session_start()`, then the test, then `session_destroy()` if it's the culprit session. That's pretty darn inefficient, but workable (especially since this is hopefully not something you do all the time).

If you switch to a database-backed session storage, you are more easily able to find and purge all sessions of a particular user with regular SQL queries.

Comment: But User A and User B would have completely different session files.  How would I associate User B's session file with the value for a specific SESSION key of User A?  I just inspected the session files and didn't see specific key/value pairs or anything obvious.

Comment: You would obviously be saving the user's id in the session, to identify the logged in user in the first place. And if user B logs in with user A's password, he's authenticated as user A. So you want to purge all sessions of user A.

Comment: Actually I do see the session data is stored unencrypted in the file, so going to take a stab at this approach

Comment: Ok, after confirming you can read the data from the session files and this approach would technically work, I'd be worried about actually implementing something like this for a web app due to the security considerations.  IE if my php backend can read/write from the sessions directory, it seems like that could be used as an exploit.

Comment: Your PHP code can read/write to those sessions anyway. But yes, you want  to keep this far away from public code, maybe just as a cron-job script or such.